# String manipulation in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

Given an array :

```
1.9.2p290 :172 >   tags_array = %w[one two]
 => ["one", "two"] 
1.9.2p290 :173 >
```

how can operate on it to have back (exactly) the following String ?

```
[/^one/i, /^two/i]
```

... i get a try with this :

```
1.9.2p290 :173 > tags_array.collect! {|tag| "/^"+tag+"/i"}
 => ["/^one/i", "/^two/i"] 
1.9.2p290 :174 >
```

but I really want `[/^one/i, /^two/i]` without double quote.

Comment: Your expected result doesn't appear to be a string, but an array of regexps. You actual result is also an array of strings, not a string. Can you clarify?

Comment: forget any structure, due the first array I want a string back, the string will be composed by each element of the sourcing array, surrounded by the regexes chars (case-insensitive) ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an array of regexps, you can use string interpolation within a regex literal:

```
%w[one two].map { |tag| /^#{tag}/i }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to map `Regexp::new`:

```
tag_array.collect! { |tag| Regexp.new("^#{tag}", true) }
=> [/^one/i, /^two/i]
```

Notice `true` is passed as second parameter to `Regexp::new`: it means the resulting regular expression should be case insensitive.

Comment: I get this back :    
1.9.2p290 :187 >   tags_array = %w[one two]
 => ["one", "two"] 
1.9.2p290 :188 > tag_array.collect! { |tag| Regexp.new("^#{tag}", true) }
 => [/^(?i-mx:^(?i-mx:^one))/i, /^(?i-mx:^(?i-mx:^two))/i] 
1.9.2p290 :189 >

Comment: That's because you invoked it on an `Array` that already contained two `Regexp` objects ;) My answer is just the same as the one the other user supplied, with the only difference i used the explicit constructor: try it on the `["one", "two"]` array and it will work just fine.